# Mocha / Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js

How would I write a basic test class to compare the value of two numbers, to test a minimum value validation rule I wrote.
For example if the number I give is 10, I need to assert that a 9 "falls below the minimum value"  while if the number is 11, then it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that should to do the check; If `variable` is greater that 10, the test passes, otherwise the test fails.

```js
var assert = require('assert');
var variable = 11;
describe('comparison', function() {
  describe('#functionName()', function() {
    it('should return true when the variable is greater than 10', function() {
      assert.equal(true, variable > 10);
    });
  });
});
```